# vite and ts-node-dev don't update on file change

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, express, vite

I'm using docker for my app (server and client) so I only have to use `make build` but when I edit the files either on front or back, changes won't load in any way unless I build again. I know `vite` and `ts-node-dev` support `ts` but I can't figure it out, here is my files config and my process (using colima for docker deamon) :

```
project
├── Makefile
├── client
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── tsconfig.app.json
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── tsconfig.node.json
│   └── vite.config.ts
├── docker-compose.yml
├── package.json
└── server
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── package.json
    └── tsconfig.json
```

makefile:

```
build:
    docker-compose up --build -d

up:
    docker-compose up -d

down:
    docker-compose down

logs:
    docker-compose logs -f
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development

  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
```

### **client:**

package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
...
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

#RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

#CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

vite.config.ts:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port : 3000
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

### server

package.json :

```
...
"scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev src/app.ts",
...
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

#RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 4000

#CMD ["node", "dist/app.js"]
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "outDir": "./dist",
    ...
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```